# tortoise svn commit success but file is not commited

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

This is the first time i use tortoise svn so please bear with me.

I was commiting some files and they said it has been succeed. However, the file is not uploaded to the server.

This is the screen shoot :

[image]

As you can see, some folders are marked green but not all of them are uploaded. Tortoise wont commit my "Livescore" and "InitActivity" which is the android studio project. The other file/folder is uploaded without problem.

Please help me out, Thanks

Comment: Did you look in the log or what it looks like in the Repo Browser? Those are two ways to see what is on the server. It is possible the shell overlays did not update correctly, you changed something after the commit (forgot to save all before?), or you did not select everything that needed committing.

Answer (score 5):

If the commit has been successful and you did it from the root of your working copy, then I guess that it's just some kind of cached icons issue. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> a couple of times in the Windows Explorer and see if those icons change from red to green.

Otherwise right-click in the working copy and choose TortoiseSVN's *SVN Commit...* command. Do you see any uncommitted changes in the list ("Changes made")?

Comment: Its said nothing is changed...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the `clean-up` command in TortoiseSVN.

The reason is, at times on commit, the cache is not cleaned properly and red-icon (uncommitted changes) keeps appearing.